# Is there a way to download a previous version of Visual Studio Code in a specific format?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to download all the Visual Studio Code binaries of a specific version for various platforms, as complete as possible, so I can serve it to incompatible systems. But, the ones found in the Visual Studio Code docmentation are only 64-bit.

#### What I tried:

I previously have grabbed a copy of Microsoft Visual Studio Code (version 1.70.2, 32-bit EXE installer) from https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32/stable/. Is there any way to grab any other formats, including the portable, zipped version of Visual Studio Code and the CLI with that domain?

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, I believe so. They have a webpage for all the types of downloads [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_previous-release-versions).  Simply replace `{version}` with the version you want, or `latest` for the latest version.

| Download type | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Windows x64 System installer | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-x64/stable) |
| Windows x64 User installer | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-x64-user/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-x64-user/stable) |
| Windows x64 zip | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-x64-archive/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-x64-archive/stable) |
| Windows x64 CLI | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/cli-win32-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/cli-win32-x64/stable) |
| Windows Arm64 System installer | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-arm64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-arm64/stable) |
| Windows Arm64 User installer | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-arm64-user/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-arm64-user/stable) |
| Windows Arm64 zip | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-arm64-archive/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-arm64-archive/stable) |
| Windows Arm64 CLI | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/cli-win32-arm64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/cli-win32-arm64/stable) |
| Windows x86 System installer | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32/stable) |
| Windows x86 User installer | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-user/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-user/stable) |
| Windows x86 zip | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-archive/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-archive/stable) |
| Windows x86 CLI | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/cli-win32-ia32/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/cli-win32-ia32/stable) |
| macOS Universal | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/darwin-universal/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/darwin-universal/stable) |
| macOS Intel chip | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/darwin/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/darwin/stable) |
| macOS Intel chip CLI | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/cli-darwin-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/cli-darwin-x64/stable) |
| macOS Apple silicon | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/darwin-arm64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/darwin-arm64/stable) |
| macOS Apple silicon CLI | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/cli-darwin-arm64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/cli-darwin-arm64/stable) |
| Linux x64 | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-x64/stable) |
| Linux x64 debian | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-deb-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-deb-x64/stable) |
| Linux x64 rpm | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-rpm-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-rpm-x64/stable) |
| Linux x64 snap | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-snap-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-snap-x64/stable) |
| Linux x64 CLI | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/cli-linux-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/cli-linux-x64/stable) |
| Linux Arm32 | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-armhf/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-armhf/stable) |
| Linux Arm32 debian | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-deb-armhf/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-deb-armhf/stable) |
| Linux Arm32 rpm | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-rpm-armhf/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-rpm-armhf/stable) |
| Linux Arm32 CLI | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/cli-linux-armhf/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/cli-linux-armhf/stable) |
| Linux Arm64 | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-arm64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-arm64/stable) |
| Linux Arm64 debian | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-deb-arm64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-deb-arm64/stable) |
| Linux Arm64 rpm | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/linux-rpm-arm64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/linux-rpm-arm64/stable) |
| Linux Arm64 CLI | [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/cli-linux-arm64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/cli-linux-arm64/stable) |